# Swift 2.0 MPMusicPlayerController will not always play song on initial click

Tags: ios, swift, audio, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am new to Swift and have spent days researching, but I can't seem to figure out why my code will only play the selected song about 75% of the time when the app first "starts up".  The app has 3 VC's: Artist, Album, Songs.  When you get to the songs VC, the user clicks a song but it won't always play.  Most of the time it will (and at this moment, there isn't anything else playing).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var qrySongs = MPMediaQuery()
    var myMPMusicPlayerController = MPMusicPlayerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.myMPMusicPlayerController = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()
    // Query songs
    let predicateByAlbumTitle = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: selectedAlbumTitle, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle)
    qrySongs = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
    qrySongs.addFilterPredicate(predicateByAlbumTitle)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let myCollectionToPlay = MPMediaItemCollection(items: qrySongs.items!)
    self.myMPMusicPlayerController.setQueueWithItemCollection(myCollectionToPlay)
    self.myMPMusicPlayerController.nowPlayingItem = myCollectionToPlay.items[indexPath.row]
    print ("Starting to play selectedSongIndexNum = ", indexPath.row)
    self.myMPMusicPlayerController.prepareToPlay()
    self.myMPMusicPlayerController.play()
    if self.myMPMusicPlayerController.playbackState != .Playing {
        self.myMPMusicPlayerController.play()  // Try again
    }
    print (myMPMusicPlayerController.nowPlayingItem?.title)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "songIdCell")
    let rowItem = qrySongs.collections![indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = rowItem.items[0].title
    }
}
```

Output when it doesn't work:

Starting to play selectedSongIndexNum =  7

nil

Output when it does work (plus the song is playing):

Starting to play selectedSongIndexNum =  7

Optional("Last Child")

Keep in mind that if you click again, it will ALWAYS work (no matter which song you click on).  If you go back to Artists and then forward to Songs, it will ALWAYS work.  There are no other players playing in the background.  Thanks ahead of time for any help.

Comment: The table is populated in code you have not shown. But the problem is that you have not coordinate that code with this code. You must do the query first, then _keep its results_ and load the table. It makes no sense to do the query when the user taps; you should already have that information.

Comment: Thanks for helping.  My original post had: // Query songs, under viewDidLoad but i didn't put the code there so as to keep it short.  I've gone back and edited it so the code is there now.    Doesn't the code in viewDidLoad get executed before the other functions?  If so, I believe that I am doing the query first.  The list of songs is always there before I can click one.

Comment: I've also added how the table gets populated: cellForRowAtIndexPath.